# 2008 Honda Civic air conditioning compressor

Tags: ac, air

A friend of mine has a 2008 Honda Civic.  She's complaining that the air conditioning is blowing out warm air. I looked at the compressor while it was running and I didn't see the outer part of the air conditioning clutch turning with the pulley when the air conditioning was turned on. It did look like the pulley moved slightly outboard when the air conditioning was turned on, but the outer part of the clutch definitely didn't turn with the pulley. It sounds to me like the air conditioning, clutch isn't engaging is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like it's not engaging, but considering the age of the car, I'd suggest it may have an issue with low refrigerant pressure which is not allowing the computer to engage the clutch on the compressor.

Comment: Go on Google and search for "TRSE07" (which should be the compressor we're talking about). Look for a picture where the clutch part can be clearly seen. What do you refer to with "outer part of the ac clutch"? The metal plate around the shaft bolt? This one, right after you engage the AC, should be rotating so fast that all you see is a blur. What does it do as soon as AC is turned on? Paulster2 is right. Most drivers have a very bad habit of not running the AC for some minutes each week, and that makes it eventually run out of refrigerant (and then, you're risking a seized compressor).

Comment: Unfortunately, the low refrigerant condition also means less oil flow and higher superheat, and that, in addition to the risk of seizure, means the compressor is overheating whenever it's run on low refrigerant - this may also mean an inoperative coil, if the coil housing is equipped with a thermal fuse redundant to the thermal switch usually featured on scroll and vane compressors.